# SSRS. Disable page access / printing if It's blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2008-r2

In report could be 2 pages:

1st page:

```
HEADER
______
Tablix1
______
FOOTER
```

2nd page:

```
HEADER
______
Tablix2
______
FOOTER
```

In `Footer` and `Header` I have added rectangles, all content from header and footer are passed to rectangles. If in `Tablix2` there is no data, rectangle from `Header`, `Tablix2` and rectangle from `Footer` in second page are hidden.

But there is problem in report preview user still can Access 2nd page, even If all content are hidden. How could I achieve that If there is no data in `Tablix2` (everything is hidden) remove 2nd page at all.

When users trying to print report It always printing 2 pages, even If 2nd page is blank. Should print only 1 page If second is blank.

Hope you understood my problem, ask me If something unclear - I'll try to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an expression for the "PageBreak->Disabled" property of an tablix, i. e. to set Tablix2 on the second page You have the "PageBreak->BreakLocation" on Tablix1 set to "End". Then you can set the "PageBreak->Disabled" property of Tablix1 to something like "isnothing(First(Fields!....Value, "DataSet2"))" to evaluate if there is data for your Tablix2 available.
If there is no data, there won't be a page break and since the Tablix2 is hidden in this case, there probably will be no great additional space requirement on page1, if there still is a problem consider setting the report property "ConsumeContainerWhitespace" to "False".